# ¿Cómo puedo guardar datos con un option <select> en mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este código pero me vota este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: BtnGuardar in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\Administracion\modificarAmbulancia.php
>   on line 41

Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos llamada `ambulancia` y tiene 2 columnas que son `placa` y `estado`.

Lo que busco es que cuando seleccionen una placa y llenen el campo del estado,
opriman el botón guardar y se guarde en la base de datos.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Modificando Ambulancia...

## Modificar Ambulancia

```
<br>
<label>Movil :</label>
<select name="Ambulancias">

<?php while ($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $arreglo['placa']?>"><?php echo $arreglo ['placa']?></option>

<?php } ?>

  option
</select>
</br>

<br> 
<label>Estado :</label>
<input type="text" name="Estado" REQUIRED>
</br>


<br>
<input type="submit" value="Volver" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Administracion/administracion.php'" style="margin-left: 3%" />
</br>

<input type="submit" name="BtnGuardar" value="Guardar">
```

Comment: Deberias de indicar cual es la linea 41 en tu codifo

Comment: if ($_POST['BtnGuardar'])

Comment: Creo que deberias poner todo el codigo.  Estas usando una forma o AJAX?

Comment: NO ESTOY UTLIZANDO AJAX NO SE PORQUE NO APARECE TODO EL CODIGO

Comment: `Undefined index: BtnGuardar` indica que BtnGuardar no esta llegando por post, puedes cambiar la linea a `if (isset($_POST['BtnGuardar'])) ` eso soluciona el error pero si no llega el valor puede haber un error en otro lado

Comment: Como lo sospechaba, no estas usando una forma.  Para que POST funcione, tiene que ser en el contexto de un FORM o utilizando el metodo POST explisitamente en AJAX

Comment: no se de ajax men

Comment: No es necesario que uses ajax, pero si necesitas por lo menos usar <form>

Comment: por eso necesito ayuda para hacerlo

Comment: Como te ha dicho alanfcm, debes colocar dentro de las etiquetas `<form></form>` todos los campos que deseas que sean enviados a la base de datos. Si desconoces aún el uso de formularios en HTML, te sugiero que leas la documentación existente por internet. [Este tutorial parece ser bueno](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form), y ante tus dudas, aquí estaremos ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es más bien sólo un aviso, no debiera interferir con tus procesos. Pero para que no aparezca, debes corregir la causa por la que sale.
En este caso, es porque estás accediendo a un índice que no existe *aún* en el arreglo `$_POST`... *Sí existirá* cuando envíes el formulario, pero mientras aún no lo hayas hecho, pues nada, no existe, y PHP te lo reclamará.

Una forma de corregirlo es cambiar esto:

```
  if ($_POST['BtnGuardar'])
```

Por esto:

```
  if (isset($_POST['BtnGuardar']))
```

Con más práctica, descubrirás muchas más maneras de manejar esta situación, pero para empezar, puedes probar con la que te sugiero.

Comment: muchas gracias funciono pero no me guarda los datos.

Comment: Viendo la parte de tu código en donde realizas la inserción, usas 2 variables: `$placa`y `$estado`: ¿en qué parte las declaras y les asignas su valor? Y más aún: ¿Los campos de tu tabla admiten valores vacíos? Si no es el caso, entonces por eso no inserta nada...

Comment: por eso necesito ayuda men